# Why is this only appended once?

Tags: jquery, append

This loop (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mDV4D/)) tries to append a `<span>` tag to a container five times. But it only does it once. Why?

```
var myArr = [0,1,2,3,4];
var $span= $('<span></span>');
for (var i = 0; i < (myArr.length); i++) {
    $('.contain').append($span);
}
```

Comment: Not sure why but it works if you change line 2 to `var span= "<span>SPAN</span>";`.

Comment: Interesting, I tested this on my (much more complicated than this demo) code, and the suggestion in the comment above works. e.g. append a string instead of a jQuery object. Are there any disadvantages to appending a string vs. a jQuery object, or is it bad practice?

Comment: I would use a string in this case. jQuery object is good for when you are building up a complex dom element programatically (over many lines of code) or if you have used jQuery to get a dom element from the page already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're appending the same element multiple times.
Use `clone` to clone the element and then `append`.

`$('.contain').append($span.clone());`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mDV4D/1/)

**Update**:

This way you can customize your element and then clone it with all properties.

```
var $span = $('<span/>', {
                    'class': 'someClass otherClass',
                    'css': {
                         'background-color': '#FF0000'
                     }
            });
for (var i = 0; i < (myArr.length); i++) {
    $('.contain').append($span.clone());
}
```

[**demo2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mDV4D/2/)

**Update2**: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810461/why-is-this-only-appended-once/12810483#comment17325556_12810483) comment.

`$('.contain').append('<span class="yourClass"/>');`

Comment: or even simpler `$('.contain').append('<span/>');` and no $span var

Comment: @Fresheyeball I agree in this case, but this way he can customize the `$span` and append it with the same style multiple times.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann is that not possible if a string is appended? Couldn't I do `.append('<span class=myclass></span>')`?